# Spark on Emr and job (jar) submission from the master node:

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

So I am running (or trying to) a compiled (fat jar) spark/scala program from the master node of an EMR cluster on aws.  I have compiled the jar in my dev environment with all the same dependencies as my prod environment.  And I am deploying with the spark-submit script:

```
SPARK_JAR=./spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar \
./spark-submit \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--verbose \
--master yarn-cluster \
--class sparkSQLProcessor \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1 \
--num-executors 1 \
/home/hadoop/Spark-SQL-Job.jar args1 args2
```

The issue that I am running into is that I am getting this config issue: (or I assume it is)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/hadoop/.versions/spark-1.2.1.a/bin/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:289)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.copyFileToRemote(ClientBase.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$3.apply(ClientBase.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$3.apply(ClientBase.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.prepareLocalResources(ClientBase.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.createContainerLaunchContext(ClientBase.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.run(ClientBase.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

I run spark jobs on EMR all the time, but never encountered this error. Are you using the EMR bootstrap action to install spark or using the newer EMR 4.0 version?

Either way you should try without setting the SPARK_JAR environment variable.